# Ionic View transition flickering

Tags: ionic-framework

There are problem with view transition, leaving view takes time to display view and overlap enter view.
In my app.js config

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

And Index html

```
 <ion-nav-view cache-view="true" >
```

Comment: can you provide more detail on the issue, the detail given is insufficient  to understand the issue

Comment: Issue has been resolved I forgot to add ionic.css in my index.html